# Cloudflare will add X-Robots-Tag to some pages

Tags: cloudflare, x-robots-tag

Recently I find Cloudflare will add X-Robots-Tag(noindex, follow) to some of our pages. For example:

https://www.datanumen.com/fr/blogs/chatgpt-join-drawing-exam/

The response header in Chrome is below:

[image]

To make sure the flag is set by Cloudflare, I do the following check:

1. Check all .htaccess files and confirm there is no setting of X-Robots-Tag.
2. Use [www.webpagetest.org](http://www.webpagetest.org) script to setDNS to our server's IP directly, to bypass Cloudflare, as below:

```
setDns www.datanumen.com ##.##.##.##
navigate https://www.datanumen.com/fr/blogs/chatgpt-join-drawing-exam/
```

Then the response header will **NOT** contain X-Robots-Tag any more, the result is at https://www.webpagetest.org/result/231201_AiDcS6_52V/1/details/#waterfall_view_step1

So how to prevent Cloudflare from adding X-Robots-Tag?

I check some related posts:

https://community.cloudflare.com/t/apo-cache-inserts-x-robots-tag-noindex-follow-header/377185
https://community.cloudflare.com/t/x-robots-tag-setting/58774
https://community.cloudflare.com/t/noindex-sent-to-google-crawling-bot/51113/10

but still cannot solve the issue.

Comment: I don't see that header on https://www.datanumen.com/fr/blogs/chatgpt-join-drawing-exam/ on any of the three methods I tried (Firefox, Chrome, and curl)

Comment: @NickODell try incognito, or use vpn with exit nodes somewhere robots often originates from.

Comment: *"So how to prevent Cloudflare from adding X-Robots-Tag?"* - have you tried to raise the issue to Cloudflare support? i think it is part of their (anti)robot measures.

Comment: @BagusTesa, Yes, I asked on both their community https://community.cloudflare.com/t/cloudflare-will-add-x-robots-tag-to-some-pages/586986 and raise a ticket.

Comment: @alancc anyway, i reckon cloudlfare would respect origin server's header. perhaps you can override it by adding your own [`x-robots-tag`](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots-meta-tag) that still allow (google)bots to crawl your site. something like `nositelinkssearchbox` or `max-snippet` directive might be useful.

Comment: @BagusTesa, the cases are that I want some pages to be indexed, while some not(such as tag pages). So I use robot meta tags to control that. If using x-robots-tag, then either I need to write a very complex rule for different cases, or it will conflict with the existing robot meta tags.

Comment: *"I need to write a very complex rule for different cases"* - thats part of being a [webadmin](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). i see your site is built using [tag:wordpress], there are many ways (and plugins) that can help you in adding custom headers to each pages.